# jQuery make animation in pseudo after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my markup and css like this

```
<div class="box">Box Content</div>
```

css goes like this

```
    <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes widthresize {
        0% {
            width:10px
        }
        50% {
            width:50px
        }
        100% {
            width:100px
        }
    }
@-moz-keyframes widthresize {
        0% {
            width:0%
        }
        50% {
            width:50%
        }
        100% {
            width:100%
        }
}
@-ms-keyframes widthresize {
        0% {
            width:0%
        }
        50% {
            width:50%
        }
        100% {
            width:100%
        }
}
@keyframes widthresize {
        0% {
            width:0%
        }
        50% {
            width:50%
        }
        100% {
            width:100%
        }
    }   
    body {
        background-color: #333;
    }
    .box {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .box::after {
        background: #FFF;
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        width: 0;
        height: 1px;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
    .widthanimation::after {
      -webkit-animation-name: widthresize;
      -moz-animation-name: widthresize;
      -o-animation-name: widthresize;
      -ms-animation-name: widthresize;
      animation-name: widthresize;
      animation-timing-function: ease;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
      -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
      -o-animation-timing-function: ease;
    }

    </style>
```

and the jQuery like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.box').addClass('widthanimation');
});
```

I want that when jQuery adds class widthanimation to the div then in pseudo after it will start to animate the width to 100%. For animation I have used css keyframe which you can see in the css. But its not working at all. Sorry but I can't change my markup. So can someone tell me how to get the animation with this markup? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. The fiddle link can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/qam24kzb/) Thanks.

Comment: It's not working because you didn't specify how long the animation should take to complete: https://jsfiddle.net/qam24kzb/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the quick reply but can you tell me how to keep it fix after 100% width. Means once it gets 100% it should not change anymore.

Comment: no problem, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you didn't specify how long the animation should take to complete. Try this:

```
.widthanimation::after {
    -webkit-animation: widthresize 1s ease;
    -moz-animation: widthresize 1s ease;
    -o-animation: widthresize 1s ease;
    -ms-animation: widthresize 1s ease;
    animation: widthresize 1s ease;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qam24kzb/1)

Note that `1s` is 1 second. You can adjust this as you require.

To stop the animation at the 100% keyframe, use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`:

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qam24kzb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS animation seems a bit overkill, could you not just transition?

https://jsfiddle.net/9qc2yg59/

```
.box::after {
    background: #FFF;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out; 
    transition: width 1s ease-out; 
}
.box.widthanimation::after {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Is the fiddle animated for you?